# How to rotate Seaborn heatmap in python?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, axis-labels, yaxis

default settings of `seaborn.heatmap` gives

[image]

- the x-axis starts from the origin of 0 then increases towards the
  right
- the y-axis starts from an origin of 9 then increases towards the
  upward

This is odd compared to `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`, which gives a y-axis that starts from an origin of 0 that moves upward, like what we'd intuitively want since it only makes sense for origins to be (0,0), not (0,9)!

How to make the y-axis of `heatmap` also start from an origin of 0, instead of 9, moving upward? (while of course re-orienting the data correspondingly)

I tried transposing the input data, but this doesn't look right and the axes don't change. I don't think it's a flip about the y-axis that's needed, but a simple rotating of the heatmap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flip the y-axis using `ax.invert_yaxis()`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

If you want to do the rotation you describe, you have to transpose the matrix first:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data.T)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

The reason for the difference is that they are assuming different coordinate systems. `pcolormesh` is assuming that you want to access the elements using cartesian coordinates i.e. `[x, y]` and it displays them in the way you would expect. `heatmap` is assuming you want to access the elements using array coordinates i.e. `[row, col]`, so the heatmap it gives has the same layout as if you print the array to the console.

Why do they use different coordinate systems? I would be speculating but I think it's due to the ages of the 2 libraries. `matplotlib`, particularly its older commands is a port from `Matlab`, so many of the assumptions are the same. `seaborn` was developed for Python much later, specifically aimed at statistical visualization, and after `pandas` was already existent. So I would guess that [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom) chose the layout to replicate how a `DataFrame` looks when you print it to the screen.

Comment: any idea why `plt.pcolormesh` does it properly be default and `seaborn.heatmap()` gives an inverted transpose of what `pcolormesh` does by default? Or is it the other way around and `pcolormesh` is doing the orientation wrong, while `heatmap` is right? which of the two is doing it right?

Comment: Answer updated - they're both right for different coordinate systems!